# Filtering performance with large lists

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have a list of ~5000 elements and I would like to filter it by `searchPhrase` which is given by user.
Usually user types first letter of filtering phrase, then second and then third.
For example user types `'a'`, then `'ab'`, then `'abc'`.

I'm trying to use reactjs/reselect library to improve filtering performance.
I have used this lib as in Example on readme:
[Example](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#selectorsindexjs) 
I have changed this method:

```
export const getVisibleTodos = createSelector(
  [ getVisibilityFilter, getTodos ],
  (visibilityFilter, todos) => {
    switch (visibilityFilter) {
      case 'SHOW_ALL':
        return todos
      case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
        return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
      case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
        return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    }
  }
)
```

to that implementation:

```
export const getVisibleTodos = createSelector(
    [getSearchPhrase, getTodos],
    (searchPhrase, todos) => {
        return todos.filter((x) => {
            return x.firstName.indexOf(searchPhrase) >= 0;
        });
    }
)
```

I noticed that each time when user types next letter `todos.length` property is the same.
Shouldn't `todos.length` be shorter when `searchPhrase` is longer?
I think that performance without reactjs/reselect is the same.

Is that possibility to filter shorter `todos` list when previous `searchPhrase` is substring of actual `searchPhrase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how reselect improves performance: the actual filtering of the todos takes exactly the same time with or without reselect.

What reselect does for you is to memoize the filtering: as long as `getSearchPhrase` and `getTodos` return the same value (as defined by `===` equality), calling `getVisibleTodos` multiple times does the filtering only once.

This is important in a complex app, where you have many unrelated changes to redux state: without reselect any change to the state would result in all selectors being run again, even if that part of the state is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So I misunderstood features of this library. Have you ever met any library that helps in similar situations?